# Setting bios to load from USB on Razer laptop

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios

I am having issues with BIOS setting and retaining USB as the boot source on a Razer laptop running Ubuntu 18 which I want to restore Windows 10.

I am trying to follow the steps in the **To install windows** section of [this](https://insider.razer.com/index.php?threads/wanting-to-re-install-windows-on-my-blade-from-boot-usb.21338/#post-331118) post.

My USB had been ExFat formatted using my Mac and I downloaded a *Windows recovery or installation media*. I copied the contents of the recovery iso to my USB using the following command:

```
cp -r /Volumes/CCCOMA_X64FRE_EN-US_DV9/* /Volumes/Windows10
```

With all that done, the Razer BIOS does not retain the settings to boot from USB.

A picture of the boot order before I set it to USB:
[image]

Confirmation of my USB boot setting:
[image]

Saved and exited BIOS:
[image]

After exiting BIOS I still get the following Ubuntu select screen:
[image]

I force shutdown and restart the computer but it still goes to Ubuntu.

When I restart and inspect the BIOS, the USB has reverted back to Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you tried booting this "windows iso" from another machine?  I find the method of putting the media on a drive suspicious.   I am betting that the reason your wishes aren't being adhered to is because the USB stick is not bootable and the bios is going on to option#2.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: Correct! I just found out I should have been using Fat32.